# Decide if it is possible, by successively switching the place of rows or columns, to reach to the matrix$ −A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

> Let A be an n × n matrix whose entries are 0,1,−1 and each row and column has exactly one 1 and one −1. Decide if it is possible, by successively switching the place of rows or columns, to reach to the matrix −A.

i don't which method i can chose to use, please give a hint or answer.

Answer (score 0):

The basic move is as follows:

Given
$A = \left(\begin{array}{rr} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right)$.
Switching rows and then columns provides $-A = \left(\begin{array}{rr} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$.

Since each row and column has only one entry $\pm 1$, this basic move iterated leads from $A$ to $-A$.

Comment: @ Wuestenfux , every row and columns should have both one 1 and -1